# Django-role-permission duplicate queries

Tags: python, django-2.0

I am using django-role-permission in my django project and am controlling access to the views through a decorator as follows:

```
@canAccessDashboard
def index(request):
    """ Merchant settings main page"""
    try:
        return render(request, 'dashboard/merchantsettings.html')
    except Exception as e:
        return HttpResponse('NOK', status=500)
```

The decorator `canAccessDashboard is as follows:

```
def canAccessDashboard(func):
    def func_wrapper(*args):
        user = cache.get('UserObj_' + str(args[0].user.id))
        if user is None:
            user = User.objects.get(id=args[0].user.id)
            cache.set('UserObj_' + str(args[0].user.id), user, 300)
        if has_permission(user, "access_dasboard"):
            if not has_permission(user, "add_merchant_address"):
                return render(args[0], 'dashboard/specify_address.html')
            return func(*args)
        return redirect(settings.VERIFY_REGISTRATION_URL)
    return func_wrapper
```

The issue is that whenever am using the decorator am getting 8 duplicate queries, Below is an extract of queries from django-debug-toolbar:

> SELECT ••• FROM "auth_permission" INNER JOIN
>   "auth_user_user_permissions" ON ("auth_permission"."id" =
>   "auth_user_user_permissions"."permission_id") INNER JOIN
>   "django_content_type" ON ("auth_permission"."content_type_id" =
>   "django_content_type"."id") WHERE
>   "auth_user_user_permissions"."user_id" = 16 ORDER BY
>   "django_content_type"."app_label" ASC, "django_content_type"."model"
>   ASC, "auth_permission"."codename" ASC
>   Duplicated 8 times.
>
> SELECT ••• FROM "auth_permission" WHERE
>   ("auth_permission"."content_type_id" = 4 AND
>   "auth_permission"."codename" = 'add_merchant_address')
>   Duplicated 8 times
>
> SELECT ••• FROM "auth_permission" WHERE
>   ("auth_permission"."content_type_id" = 4 AND
>   "auth_permission"."codename" = 'immediate_cashout')
>   Duplicated 8 times.
>
> SELECT ••• FROM "auth_permission" WHERE
>   ("auth_permission"."content_type_id" = 4 AND
>   "auth_permission"."codename" = 'access_dasboard')
>   Duplicated 8 times

It seems it is querying the database for each Permission defined in the `available_permissions`

```
available_permissions = {
        'access_dasboard': False,
        'add_merchant_address': False,
        'immediate_cashout': False,
        'update_merchant_address': False
    }
```

Is it an issue how am using the `django-role-permissions` ? How can I reduce the duplicate queries?

Thank you.

Comment: The authentication middleware has already fetched `request.user` from the database. You don’t have to cache it. Try removing that code and seeing what queries you get then.

Comment: Removing the cache result in having the same duplicate queries.